# Problem with a custom DataTemplate written in pure C# code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I've this piece of XAML code:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="detailsCellTemplate">
        <StackPanel>

            <TextBlock Padding="3, 5, 3, 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="DemiBold">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding Path="client_title" />
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Padding="3, 0, 3, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding Path="client_subtitle" />
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

that represents a DataTemplate for a GridColumn Cell, translated in pure C# code (more or less) in this way:

```
FrameworkElementFactory stackPanelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        stackPanelFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Vertical);

        FrameworkElementFactory title = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        title.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("client_title"));
        title.SetValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
        title.SetValue(TextBlock.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible);
        stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(title);

        FrameworkElementFactory subTitle = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        title.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("client_subtitle"));
        stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(subTitle);

        VisualTree = stackPanelFactory;
```

and assigned to a ListView control with this instruction: `gridColumn.CellTemplate = new TitleCellTemplate();`, on a previously added DataContext extracted from a mysql dataset.
The Dataset binds without errors with the ListView, but all the rows in the grid are white, like they don't have a style or something.

Where could be the mistake?

Comment: Have you verified that this isn't a binding problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a binding issue. You need to set the `Source` property of your bindings.

See [Creating a binding in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx#BindinginCode) on MSDN.